# Does ZXING code scanner also return a picture of the scanned code?

Tags: android, zxing

Any ideas if ZXING library for android, besides format and data, can also return an image of the code it just scanned?

Thank!

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

***

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
           if (requestCode == 0) {
              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                 String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                 ///NEED TO GET BITMAP OF THE SCANNED CODE
                 ...
              } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                 ...
              }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not return this. Look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) to see what it constructs as a response.